Python DataFrame.info Output Doesn't Reflect Dropped Rows
I have a dataset with 2111 rows in it.  When I drop the 27 duplicate rows the DataFrame.info output still shows the rows numbered from 0 to 2110, but reports 2085 rows.
Is there a refresh command associated with DataFrame metadata I need to call?
Original unpreprocessed DataFrame.info output:
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!     Size and shape and info before preprocess
    40109
    (2111, 19)
    <bound method DataFrame.info of          id  Gender  Age  Height  Weight  ...     TUE        CALC                 MTRANS           NObeyesdad      BMI
    0         1  female   21  1.6200      64  ...  3 to 5          no  public_transportation        normal_weight  24.3865
    1         2  female   21  1.5200      56  ...  0 to 2   sometimes  public_transportation        normal_weight  24.2382
    2         3    male   23  1.8000      77  ...  3 to 5  frequently  public_transportation        normal_weight  23.7654
    3         4    male   27  1.8000      87  ...  0 to 2  frequently                walking   overweight_level_i  26.8519
    4         5    male   22  1.7800      90  ...  0 to 2   sometimes  public_transportation  overweight_level_ii  28.3424
    ...     ...     ...  ...     ...     ...  ...     ...         ...                    ...                  ...      ...
    2106  2,107  female   21  1.7107     131  ...  3 to 5   sometimes  public_transportation     obesity_type_iii  44.9015
    2107  2,108  female   22  1.7486     134  ...  3 to 5   sometimes  public_transportation     obesity_type_iii  43.7419
    2108  2,109  female   23  1.7522     134  ...  3 to 5   sometimes  public_transportation     obesity_type_iii  43.5438
    2109  2,110  female   24  1.7394     133  ...  3 to 5   sometimes  public_transportation     obesity_type_iii  44.0715
    2110  2,111  female   24  1.7388     133  ...  3 to 5   sometimes  public_transportation     obesity_type_iii  44.1443

    [2111 rows x 19 columns]


After preprocessing drops 27 duplicate rows from a dataset (going from 2111 rows to 2085).  Post row dropping, DataFrames.info output shows:
    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!     Size and shape After preprocess
    37512     
    (2084, 18)
    <bound method DataFrame.info of       Gender  Age  Height  Weight  FHWO  FAVC  FCVC  NCP  CAEC  SMOKE  CH2O  SCC  FAF  TUE  CALC  MTRANS  NObeyesdad      BMI
    0          2   21  1.6200      64     2     1     2    3     2      1     2    1    1    2     1       3           2  24.3865
    1          2   21  1.5200      56     2     1     3    3     2      2     3    2    4    1     2       3           2  24.2382
    2          1   23  1.8000      77     2     1     2    3     2      1     2    1    3    2     3       3           2  23.7654
    3          1   27  1.8000      87     1     1     3    3     2      1     2    1    3    1     3       5           3  26.8519
    4          1   22  1.7800      90     1     1     2    1     2      1     2    1    1    1     2       3           4  28.3424
    ...      ...  ...     ...     ...   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...    ...   ...  ...  ...  ...   ...     ...         ...      ...
    2106       2   21  1.7107     131     2     2     3    3     2      1     2    1    3    2     2       3           7  44.9015
    2107       2   22  1.7486     134     2     2     3    3     2      1     2    1    2    2     2       3           7  43.7419
    2108       2   23  1.7522     134     2     2     3    3     2      1     2    1    2    2     2       3           7  43.5438
    2109       2   24  1.7394     133     2     2     3    3     2      1     3    1    2    2     2       3           7  44.0715
    2110       2   24  1.7388     133     2     2     3    3     2      1     3    1    2    2     2       3           7  44.1443

    [2084 rows x 18 columns]

NOTE: the info output shows the last row numbered 2110, but rows as 2084.
I've tried using DataFrame.dropduplicates with both inplace=True and inplace=False, but the result is the same:
#Example of inplace = False and inplace=True
return_df = return_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=False)
return_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

Here's the relevant row dropping code:
        # removing duplicates
        count_dup = return_df.duplicated().sum()
        if (verbose > 0):
            print (f"Number of Duplicates : {count_dup}")
        if count_dup > 0:
            if (verbose > 0):
                print ("Dropping Duplicates")
            #return_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
            return_df = return_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=False)
        else:
            if (verbose > 0):
                print ("No duplicates found.")
        
        return return_df


The rows are being dropped correctly. However please note that the index won't automatically reset after dropping the duplicates. You need to reset the index to get your desired output:
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

Awesome!  I figured it was just a step I left out!  Thanks for confirming!

As mentioned here, inplace=True is not to be recommended.
Instead, use:
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

